# Как в TreeView оставить checkbox-ы только на листах дерева?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

В windows form проекте нужно чтобы на листах TreeView были checkbox'ы.
В свойствах TreeView есть CheckBoxes, но он не подходит, т.к. тогда на всех узлах в дереве есть CheckBox'ы, а нужны только на листах дерева!